# Prove that $\text{ex}\left(n, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\right) = \Theta(n^{3/2})$.

Tags: extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

I was reading the thesis http://www.renyi.hu/~keszegh/papers/szakdolgozat.pdf, and they cite Theorem 2.6 without proof (because apparently it is a well-known fact from extremal graph theory).

The extremal function $\text{ex}(n, P)$ is defined in the paper as the maximum possible number of 1's in an $n\times n$ binary matrix that avoids a pattern $P$.

Prove that $\text{ex}\left(n, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\right) = \Theta(n^{3/2})$.

Can someone post a proof here or redirect me to one? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try:

Corollary 2.4 in "On 0-1 matrices and small excluded submatrices" ([.ps](http://www.renyi.hu/~tardos/matrix.ps))

---

What occurs in the above is a citation to Theorem 1.1 in "Davenport-Schinzel theory of matrices" ([.pdf](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=4737966567A12E42AC8B193D86724DB8?doi=10.1.1.30.8581&rep=rep1&type=pdf)), which is the actual proof.

Comment: I'm looking for a proof of the theorem. Theorem 1.1 is just stated as a "classical result" without proof, so that doesn't really help me.

Comment: The references cited in "Davenport-Schinzel theory of matrices" could provide a proof for that specific statement. In this case, it seems that finding approved is more a case of searching the literature than having someone provide one. That said, particular statement seems to be a result of the Kővári-Sós-Turán (KST) theorem, which provides an upper, sharp bound for extremal graphs and matrices--a proof of which can be found here: http://math.mit.edu/~cb_lee/18.318/lecture2.pdf